# WCF generate the wsdl was different with the original wsdl which was provided to create WCF Service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wsdl

I got a original wsdl file from my boss and asked me to create a Dummy Web Service based on it. And then create a client to test it by using the new wsdl file which is generated from Dummy Web Service and it need to be exactly the same as the original wsdl. Unfortunately, I found that the new wsdl which was generated by the Dummy Web Service was different with the original one. Anyone could tell me why? How to get the same wsdl as the original one? Thanks!

What I did for this task:

1. `SvcUtil.exe /sc original.wsdl` --> to get the C# service class and implement the concrete class for it (dummy web service)
2. `svcutil /t:metadata 'http://localhost/myservice/test.svc?singlewsdl'` --> to get the new WSDL from the running dummy web service, but it will be different from the original one
3. `WSDLImp.exe` to create the proxy class of Delphi client (test client)

Comment: Can you explain "different"? What were the differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is always going to be the case. You are comparing two different WSDLs. One is a Virtual WSDL whared with your clients and used to generate a service with SvcUtil. Once you deploy the web-service, and take a look at the WSDL it shares, you now have a Concrete WSDL.

It is best practice for you to test your new service by making a service call *based on the Virtual WSDL* as this is the WSDL you are likely to share among your clients. SoaupUI is capable of generating and executing tests base on your Virtual WSDL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :-) I can use the original wsdl to generate the client to test the dummy web service and it is successful. Also, I can use the new generated wsdl by dummy web service to test the dummy web service and it is sucessful too. Only difference is that I need to change some client code if I adjust between these two different wsdl files. Because they have the different proxy class types when generating them.

Comment: Correct. So as to not double your work load, only worry about testing your new service with the Virtual WSDL, as that is the most important test.

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to Contract First Web Service Development! (Now go read my blog about it at http://abrahamdybvig.blogspot.com/2012/08/contract-first-web-services.html)

Comment: Thanks Guys. I didn't login for a long time. :-)